# USB OTG Supported Phones?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, symbian, usb-otg

I'm looking for Symbian/Android/Windows Phone which support USB OTG. I Have simple device which send very basic ascii data thro USB and I need to read data in phone application.

Is there any cellphones with USB Host support?

Comment: FYI, on quite a few devices, USB host is supported but the port either provides no power or insufficient power. If you don't succeed the first time, try using a powered USB hub in between your Android host and your client device.

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sName=&idMaker=0&idAvailability=0&YearAnnounced=0&nPriceLow=0&nPriceHigh=0&idCurrency=0&idFormFactor=0&idDualSIM=0&idQwerty=0&HeightMax=0&WidthMax=0&ThicknessMax=0&WeightMax=0&idOS=0&nminCPUMHz=0&nCPUCores=0&nminRAMMB=0&nminInternalStorageMB=0&idExpansionCard=0&idDisplay=0&nminDisplayX=0&nminDisplayY=0&nmaxDisplayX=0&nmaxDisplayY=0&fminDisplaySize=0&fmaxDisplaySize=0&nPixelDensity=0&idDisplayTech=0&idTouchscreen=0&idAccelerometer=0&idGyro=0&idCompass=0&id35mm=0&idCamera=0&idCameraFlash=0&idVideoRecorder=0&idSecondaryCamera=0&idGPS=0&bWLAN=0&idNFC=0&bEDGE=0&bGPRS=0&idBluetooth=0&bIR=0&bEmail=0&bWAP=0&bJava=0&idRadio=0&bMMS=0&idRingtones=0&sColor=&StandBy=0&TalkTime=0&sFreeText=On-the-go) is a close to complete list. I'm not sure about the android/WP development support for reading those ascii charachters though.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this list.  Be aware that some manufactures claim to have OTG support when in reality they may only support a subsection(Such as the hard drive) of the OTG spec.  I encountered this with a samgsung galaxy 10 tab.

Answer (score 3):

The hardware on the Nexus 1 (like many other phones) supports USB host mode even though the vanilla drivers that comes with it do not.

However, there's a driver available on the net that allows you to turn the support on.See here: http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/ and since it's a Google dev phone "rooting" is a supported feature, not a hack.

Answer (score 3):

Samsung Galaxy S II supports it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrKkklO_Fok

Answer (score 2):

Nokia's [Symbian^3 phones](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter1=symbian3) support USB OTG 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge none of the current WP7 devices provide USB host support (more than happy to be corrected, though :)).